# Calculate sum of one row and divide by sum of another row. Oracle view/query

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

This is my first question on here so bear with me. I have two tables in my Oracle database as following:

`modules` with fields:

- `module_code` eg. INF211
- `module_title` eg. Information technology
- `credits` eg.20

`module_progress` with fields:

- `student_id` eg. STU1
- `module_code` eg. INF211
- `module_year` eg. 1
- `module_percent` eg. 65

Each student takes 5 modules a year.

So this is what I want to put this all in one query/view if possible:

1. Find sum of module percents for a particular student
2. Find sum of all credits for each module with regards to their module percents.
3. Divide sum of module percents by sum of credits and multiply by 100 to give me an average grade.

Can this be done?

Comment: Is step 1 really needed? ie is there ever more than one record in module_progress for a given student & module?

Comment: a student can have as many modules as they want, aslong as they all add up to 120 credits. Each module is worth 10 or 20 credits so you can have a maximum of 12 modules obviously. I would need to do the following to work out the average grade... . For each module = (module percent / 10) * credits. Get the sum of this result divide by sum of credits and multiply by 100. Does that makes sense? How would I do this??

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  student_id,
        SUM(credits * module_percent) / SUM(credits) * 100.0
FROM    module_progress mp
JOIN    modules m
ON      m.module_code = mp.module_code
GROUP BY
        student_id
```

Comment: Since, as said in the original post, percents are stored as `65`, not as `0.65`, I think you should divide them by 100. But because it is also required to multiply the result of division by 100, then ultimately, I think, you just need to remove `* 100.0`.

Comment: that worked like a charm but I have realised an important problem. Let me explain...   each module can be 10 or 20 credits. Each year a student has enough modules to add up to 120 credits so I will need to do the following calculations to get the correct yearly average grade...  I would need to do the following for each module = (module percent / 10) * credits and then get the sum of that and divide it by 120. Does that makes sense? How would I do this??

Comment: @JMoorhouse: could you please provide some sample data and the desired resultset?

Comment: I have figured it out now. Will post answer on Tuesday evening because that is when my deadline passes and do not want people potentially copying my solution and getting me into trouble with the uni. Thank you for your patience and time. You helped alot :)